# How can I hide admin columns showing extra custom taxonomy fields?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'm adding extra custom taxonomy fields to a custom taxonomy called, let's say, "Beer Style" (or "beer-style", in the screenshot, for now), with extra custom fields like "Alcohol by Weight (Volume)," "Alcohol by Weight," etc, on top of the "slug" and "description" fields that go with the custom taxonomy. There's a bunch of extra fields I'd like to add, but it's fast crowding out the rest of the table listing all the taxonomy terms. Trying to figure out, is there a way to hide all the columns for the custom fields? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the class names assigned to the  and  table columns, I set a "display: none;" CSS rule to all the extra columns with the class names of the extra custom taxonomy fields that I added. Not the most sophisticated solution if you have a lot of extra custom fields like I do, but it does the job.